# ItemReader for JPARepository spring batch + spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application wherein reader will read data from a source and processor would transform it to destination db compatible POJO , and writer would write the obtained transformed POJO to destination db

Following is my jpa repository code

```
public interface MyCrudRepository extends JpaRepository<MyDbEntity, String> {

    List<MyDbEntity> findByPidBetween(String start, String end);

    List<MyDbEntity> findByPidGreaterThan(String start);

}
```

I want my reader to call findByPidBetween or findByPidGreaterThan based on the check if job parameter contains `endPid` parameter or not.

I am struggling to figure out which ItemReader to use for the same? Below is what I tried

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class MyItemReader extends RepositoryItemReader<MxGaanaDbEntity> {

@Value("#{jobParameters}")
private Map<String, JobParameter> jobParameters;


@Value("${end.pid}")
private String endpid;

private List<MyDbEntity> myDbEntities;



@Override
public void setRepository(@Qualifier("myCrudRepository")PagingAndSortingRepository<?, ?> repository) {
    super.setRepository(repository);
}

@Override
public void setMethodName(String methodName) {


    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(endpid))
        super.setMethodName("findByPIdGreaterThan");
    else
        super.setMethodName("findByPIdBetween");

}

@Override
public void setArguments(List<?> arguments) {

    JobParameter rawStartPid = jobParameters.get("startPid");



    String startPid = (String) rawStartPid.getValue();


    List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
    args.add(startPid);

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(endpid)) {
        args.add(endpid);
    }

    super.setArguments(args);

}
```

}

I keep getting following exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A PagingAndSortingRepository is required
```

Comment: Can you try to inject MyCrudRepository instead of PagingAndSortingRepository and remove the Qualifier?

Comment: I just answered this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117650/itemreader/-for-records-returned-by-crudrepository. It think those are related. Do you agree?