# ItemReader for records returned by CrudRepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application wherein reader reads from an external db and processor transforms it to the POJO of my destination db , writer will write the transformed POJO to the destination db

I am using following CrudRepository

```
public interface MyCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<MyDbEntity, String> {

    List<MyDbEntity> findByPIdBetween(String from, String to);

    List<MyDbEntity> findByPIdGreaterThan(String from);  
}
```

I wanted to know , how the ItemReader for above would look like?

Should I call `myCrudRepository.findByPidBetween(String from, String to)` in `@PostConstruct` of my ItemReader ?

Wouldnt that make the ItemReader static? As each job run would have different method parameter for `findByPidBetween`.

How should ItemReader be structured for above problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know , how the ItemReader for above would look like?

`RepositoryItemReader` is what you need. You can use it with your repository and specify the method to use to read items. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/data/builder/RepositoryItemReaderBuilderTests.java)

> each job run would have different method parameter for findByPidBetween

You can pass those as parameters to your job and use them in your reader.

Comment: `CrudRepository` is not a `PagingAndSortingRepository`